# Attempting to create a card using HTML and CSS. I’ve created most of the code, but can’t seem to figure out how to get it like the example I was given

Tags: html, css

[image]

In this screenshot, the title is "Title goes here", the secondary text is "Secondary text", and the body text is "Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding."

```
The card's root element is a <div> with a class of "card".
The card is 344px wide.
The desert picture is 194px tall.
The padding between the body text and everything else is 16px.
The color of the title text is #000.
The color of the secondary and body texts is #232F34.
The size of the person picture is 40px in diameter.
The size of the body text is 11px.
The size of the title is 22px.
For the padding or margin around any other elements, use your best judgment to make it look like the screenshot.
Transitions:
When a person moves their pointer over a picture card, then the card gets a shadow of rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) with a 0px horizontal offset, 2px vertical offset, and a blur radius of 4px.
```

I've attempted the HTML and CSS portion, but keep running into a wall. Below is the code for both.

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 344px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #232f34;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.card_image {
  height: 194px;
}

.person {
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height:50px;
}

.card-header {
  display: flex;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card body {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #232f34;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #232f34;
  padding: 16px;
}

.card card-shadow {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="card">
  <div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/Arabian_Desert_-_panoramio.jpg/544px-Arabian_Desert_-_panoramio.jpg" alt="" class="card_image">
    <div>
      <img class="person" src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20220709/ourmid/pngtree-businessman-user-avatar-wearing-suit-with-red-tie-png-image_5809521.png">
      <div class="card-header">Title goes here</div>
      <div class="card body">
        secondary text
      </div>
      <div class="card footer">
        Greyhound divisively hello couldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding
      </div>
      <div class="card card-shadow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Yes, do upload the html and css and add images from a working CDN. Click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and add the relevant HTML, CSS and frameworks

Comment: You can use bootstrap where you can get built-in card,  [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/)

Comment: <div id="container"></div>
<div class="card">
  <div>
  <img src="images/desert.jpg" alt="" class="card_image">
 <div>
  <img class="person" src="images/person-avatar.jpg">
  <div class="card-header">Title goes here</div>
  <div class="card body">
    secondary text
  </div>
  <div class="card footer">
    Greyhound divisively hello couldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding
  </div>
  <div class="card card-shadow"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>

Comment: .card{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 344px;
  padding: 16px;
  color:#232f34;
  font-size: 11px;
}


.card_image{
height: 194px;
}

.person{
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card-header{
  display: flex;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card body{
 display: flex;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #232f34;
}

.footer{
  display: flex;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #232f34;
  padding: 16px;
}

Comment: actually this is not a complex div construction but simply a figure and figcaption task.

Comment: So, instead of div utilize those two elements?

Comment: Please add this code to the *question*, not to the *comments*. Also, as suggested before, make it reproducible using the snipped editor.

Comment: I gave really clear instructions. I made you a snippet now. Next time please do so yourself

Answer (score 0):

***Try it also***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .card {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 300px;
            color: #232f34;
            background-color: bisque;
            font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
        }
        .card-body{
            padding:10px 15px;
        }
        .card-image img{
            height: 160px;
            width: 100%;
        }   
        .title-row{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .person img {
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            border-radius: 55%;
        }  
        .title{
            padding-left:15px ;
        }
        .title h3{            
            margin: 0px;
        }  
        .card-desc{
            padding-top: 15px;
        }
        .card:hover{
            /* transform: scale(1.1); */
            transition-duration: .3s;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        }        
    </style>
</head>

<body>    
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD84QzQ5OjcBCgoKDQwNGg8PGjclHyU3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3N//AABEIAHcAtAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAABBQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAAECBAUGB//EAEAQAAIBAgQDBgMGAwUJAQAAAAECAwARBBIhMQUTQSJRYXGBkTKh8AYUI0KxwRVi0UNScuHxFiQzU3OCkrLSB//EABoBAAMBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBgX/xAAiEQACAgICAgMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIRAyESURQxBBNBUiL/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/APQOWANh6UMqRtVqwpDKOlFmfAp5GtuKjyHOwq8SpO1Np3UWTwRVWF0N9KgyEHU+lXT4CoFQdxTsHBFbLfc2pxGhGr60coKYIOgF6LFwIrhlYXvpUvuqn4Wqawk9bCjogUADXxospQXRVOHkG1jQmWRdxWjaosinpRYPGUUsTZr0dUQUXlKetqHJGV1A076A40JlQ93rTWFVo5xKWFirKxXKx1+iNab75CrIGexbNa6n8psb921AuSLRAqNqV9L3v4ioltKYD21qWUUPPSMlFBaC3ApZqr8zWmL0ULkgxNKq+Y09Ohcy/c/3ae57hQAxp+Z41ma2Ft32FRtSD0s1zQA4UHc1IIKhY0/aGwpgTsOoFQY9FCjxpxm609l7qAIZyvUnypjOR+SpFT30r23oAGcUButOuJB0a1T0pjGrA2A87UC2M2JijjZ3bRe5ST7CqPG+MJw+HL92klLqbNbsg7C/mTasfjXGYopp4UZopsOFcOhBuQfhbpa9vnXPrx9vu86M2bOo2lNjfz179rWv4Vz5MyWkJyLnF8WMThcLKksiYkKY5Tl0Li1r9+hPjaqcHFpua7SK8isqorNfKANbXG97d/WszF55UKwsIVsRmzZtLdxPh9WqrJxFxGGbElrEKA2zWIvYHyrn5Sk7RFHbJ9pubLiFijLBlAgRfytoLX+vStnAYg4jBxyOymUr2wGBsRoR5jrXB4biPLmwheJQsbqxWI3LBdST47fQrrOE8QwkuWbFSQRmzLGH0Yak+mhtXRhzW6YmrNQtpcGhl9ahg50xsZlEkQjQtnsdtez5ab+dHbDWOprsTT9GLjJEM2m9LP40ORCuxvQJC3QU6Jcmi5npVn55O80qfEX2G8QRTDN/doI5l9b1Icz+asDssOoPdT6/3TQ0cgdq9EEinQNbzoKFm86cN4mldOpFQNulAwofS1jT3FBBHeae/jQILemZFJ1JqGandc6EFmXxU2IoARjy3JkIA3v0rPbimQGF1MeKKlgh1AHprt5a1y/2u4ni8JnwkmIDgkfhta7C/Z2Fq59uM8Tlhy4tMQyqp/E1a9rA2a+g6Eg1i8kn6QjQ+08eG5wGGl5kshtMzKQSe63ffW1UcLwZcbLBh3vhcY0tnjkTKwQjTx/08Kqwvjo4ebicHI0N1JkMatdd9b3YDbbxq/hOIQTSYnG4Gd4Ehg5kayakyKe8WNtSNTmtr3VMY17CgHEEm4ViJoZ2RZA+YpCl7L3XIF/Kw9aBhopBFiZYZXNkVlTOAWB3A7yLmq32ink4kz4woQpym6KbBT8I99P61Xhnw00Sl4lVoxl+K4Oo6e9RwrYqIyy4n7yWV5SWN75rkjvv/WriO82HSeJyZGAzNmOYH9/9ayuZJDlV2KqNezrmH9LVoYSFlZic74c7hWsbHr57aab05xWgaOk4Fxud5II8fjBHFE5crYZW89LnY2/zBHcQYiGWGNlxCuW2zEA3Iva3kRpXlWGkeNs47JIIjI0Pjr0vet7CcbkXDxRnEKZpTYF7mQGwsGJHXbT5b1ePJxdEtHcFUcaG58DQHgNz2rVR4GuHgwKrhoZo81nbmqbsdr367VbecA11xbaMZNfpBojfcGlTZ760qsy0a2R7kKL2qPNyGzi1HD91SYows63HlXOd9ARMCN6ZQH+IgCmkw0Vrozeh2oeQptJfzWgWwpVL704CUHOANSL+VIOvRhemKyxZRUbA0HMSd1PrUwx30oHYZEF9zR1Wwtc+dARwRe4owe66W86QzmeJcHwUUiYrHSAuXY5UBu19lHjbras5MJDxGSZYnGIwbIeREQ8QU7C2lup338a7RwHK31t0oEsLSyKr5WjOrGwvfw+ulTxGjzvFQvi8S78rCRaZMruA1wdwraZtd7npU+M8PixeEw08XDFkexSVxlz5wO8Nbu8BpavQlw0MMzTlSZCAvMO9hfrv1NYnEODsrDEcGZY5rkzRuLLPfrto3jb9qXFjbPOzBPJwbAwBozFjMSIocUGvyr2zI2gP5QR4A0b/AGfxEnEOIYLB5pRh2GeQ6agbW6G2m5ofH3l4NxPB4uXCTwsJDPJh5SWV3XZg2x0Nuh06XFdHg+KYbgPBmweGmOL49NmzJEmZnmc7kgbDTwtTaEck/DJG+/SK2dYJGiWQm6OVGZwCdz3DuFAw+ccw/irIgu97Wt3Wtt4V6Xw7gUOF4RgsNmZZ4l/FlB1ZiDmbzuxsaGPsvAcTBiRjpecukzEX5o/b0qZRbJdHCphYuWs+K5/w3j+7gAXvre+2/lTRYbEyYxOHrFL95DdtAgBYXsCDfTfXy869D4rwnDyYcDCQwhou0iaAE3ufInvrF4X9neVM5xtyquDDIslmTrfx38NqrgJyR0fClmXCLh5YpEMKBc0hFm8rdKK6hd0BqPPsgDSZ2G7bXqJxI7xW8VSMJOJE5b/D86VIzRE3IF6VVZnrs2Negp87DTK3pWMvF3ygnlG25BppeMSxXN4wAdt6+e/lYzs5I3M7EW19abesEcZn1IaJrHbLUjxbGXGSNGuL2tS8vEHJG5lB3ApsiH8i+1YTcaxSg3gTQeNOvG8UWsYYwdxcXH60/LxdhyRumJBrlX0pwF7rCsFuK4wkZWwuo6owt86SccnueYmHIG5GZbe9X5GL+hc0bnKF9G9xUgoGwPoKy4eNxtbmRgX2yPe/uBRm4xhhawkPku1HkYv6HaLpNtyfaok/zVT/AIvhb/2oO9stSPFcKWsyzW/6dPyMfYFkqp+KQ3qLRqR/xG96r/xPCWuFky/4accRwR3DD0p/fj7DRh/bXhP8R4NMRKc8C82O69RuL+IvWd/+bYeN+HTY+R8+KnkyvLJ2mCgAAXOv14V1UuN4fJHJFJezAqeyeulcz9hMJNwLC4nDcSaPIXV4nBzdLHTpsKX34+xnYDmbZhbypLEz9Y9O8GgfxLBFSfvCC29xapLj8KxsMRGT51X2wfphSLBjygXVfQUrDqBTLKraIwPkae9hciqTv0GhuVHvlS/+GmMKH+zjP/aKfmDW9qQmjXpensNEfusHXDx/+IpqnzQdlpUbD/JwLhc+jAK1/fpRUGgs6sAOp276JLhYTGRG4HaACk6a/RoEUCmDmWJFjr16a15+zIsJFnvJY5tRYGnMIIYIZI2Bvo19fKs+TGNHYRBlspuXFr6kUNeLSjMVBe1ra3J6b0AbaJPkuXAzG1uoFLLI2gxQ06VjR4t8RKwDEtbbr51ahyHJmV8zi3kamxlzPOic1cRmjbWwUEgVNnxGgujWF77A0GCeNWUFeza506HT+tTw00Lhmcm7bW+EiobEWIi+Z+Y19dgNtKSLcAsilW1NtDVRuIKYyqsAUcKQARfvo2GxUcqBuaBcEW6g9f3p2MsrAgNhCtvPxpzEL9mNffX6vVRsUSgU7q/aUnp3igffdSWYNtkNtd6doRouVjILNbwtTS8tQWZVP8wOtZeIxwd7SDLexYqel7Ajw2qtIZioHMY5WG2twRqPejkOzXM8CMgFxmBI/UVFpIHdgxy22I2asjDYhlMkJRnVbEd9ul6K0i3kRkYA6qNiKT0KzRDYa7Mri1rWJ8Lj9ajHAszEK4FtbHpfX9xWVI4ylxazDcaXBOh+u6pxTBZ1UysHZQfA3W1/eppDs1eSy2KuSCM2/fUvvEuHXWV1v1BrMjx4hlSKQntEg3PwjenfHQzOczhrMRpsbf601yW4sLNEcdxUdryBwFvqKg32qnHZKRE92U1gy4qPKy3GVltcHUAmoYeaJgoL/EPn3fOumGbPFXYmzUl+02PzkhItfE0qoiMMAWZLnrl3+dKn5WTsewWHx2ZZIzIc9gV7j9ftR+H4iR52i3TKbZuul/2FZEIa7PHEheM6xFrXG437/TatfDSRpDzFjNohl0106g9NrGonBLaEWEmR4/xIzYm/sfoelPlw0cqvygsWYjOBubeFNPPHqXhKg/iLrcHv996zsQMkscYb8DFBhmItZh33+t6hJv0BqPNCYlaWMCaLN01sP1FtaebEZsMSpFxd1t+a3T2FUJA0mEj55y4iNbhu/Xcd/X1FSYthshKAZlNtLBxpceelDQFpEaWNJomsXXMBe2bT+tKcNHKAnY2ZQDbKbbfr86CjxhFEZORibxsbjKfHpQ4cU7KcNOGYBuUSV7QuDlPzPzrOgDPhnkj/AAUBfMQ4vswBI/Whyo8UcXIQtIbOT1BJ1HlViPE5JOcxzc8AsB0NhY+4o3NaaTDvlOjBJbHbYgjw1v4CkhlOVQk6OmZUkcqSNcmoF/erUQRFLTPfJ8SlrKR4fpQcQ2djMA1oZLsVFxlta+nSh4uV4sMr3/3iEozgjdCSDf2arqwDMkSlAQHUBraA3Xf+ntUQ8TaI1swswYXzDprWPiObE+JMTWCpmSx+E6doejfrQhJLNhrxEkhTkXcHKxI+WlWsLauwNMzE4pZDcFVJVlPatf52PypNiwoiLMNXJDDY+XdprWPNjZlxJzDJNKFyg9GuDr5638vGnxWLLzHDkZ4pFAj8GNyPW+nrWi+O20hUamInUCJV1JIHob/LQ+tVJ53aAurHmKSgAGtrg/uaoxYl/u8RksFcqWXoLHQ/L6tQ2kCpksyyF8xFt1I109a0h8fYUaWIxKTowIynmFWZdyB18za3tVWSVSFLNKiu5+BQFB7t76eVUIWMs35mAW56m99P2+dTMipaRbyKvaZr2+tz7V0RwqOhUWXzMCV1Oa9u4X0qaMW5YBYHN06nTvqumJaGElsxVRluNT61YGMRIrgXAuMwG50G3rUOMuhUywkrgW7TAaAmlVX77/y7266b0qx4S6A6REimiLSCTlMFKsz3aNr2tf1qWHwv3GeZkYPBKBnjOgtawIH1pSpVzObRQ7LEhEJByZuzYm1wbWt0vpTciM3hKh0zB0Vum1/I/LWlSqbdgDeNAFk0YAkMBfa4197UeY2tE6AwtY99idNj4tSpUfoGexeBy0ZUoqg5TsRf/IAjyIq4IY5jGFGjPZSNGUjtDz0/elSqn+DMqGWYjmAkty9vRbj5D3q+GEYR72SMhzfcIw2/ypUqJ+wGjZ4S6rZhEdf5wVufcCguqyyABiCqBOYNyApsfO4+dKlSj7Ap4l1lMpVcrAhrHwym3la/tQZV5WGjdLMiLIvd8IJHuGp6VdUNKIFeWJfwpSo+FXK95VVP/wBVCVHjlKM12ZXZCNMpAbX2A+VKlW8WxoFiQy4cRyk3VCbXvqBmP/tQJJS/JuQHyAAC+tgND7fOlSrfGr2ESEMzKSJAGjNgxO4vtUUPJlc3DrbMQb+BvSpVs0rKLmHcFA9hkLX7rDS4PpSKIrMoUWuQDbuO3sBSpVzPTZH6x2jaLsINASfiItck2+dKlSpWI//Z" alt="" >
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="title-row">
                <div class="person">
                    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                    <span>secondary text</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-desc">
                Greyhound divisively hello couldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card_container {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  padding: 5px;
  
  height: 300px
}
.card_box {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card_img_box {
  height: calc(100% - 124px);
  overflow: hidden
}
.card_img_box img {
  width: 100%;
}
.card_content_box {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 padding: 15px;
}
.user_box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.user_profile {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.user_profile img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.user_title {
  flex: 1 1 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.user_main_text {
   font-size: 24px;
   color: #232323;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.user_sub_text {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #686868;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.card_text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #686868;
}
```

```html
<div class="card_container">
  <div class="card_box">
    <div class="card_img_box">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/walk-desert-7831049.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="card_content_box">
      <div class="user_box">
        <div class="user_profile">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
        </div>
        <div class="user_title">
          <div class="user_main_text">Titile Here</div>
          <div class="user_sub_text">Sub text Here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card_text">
        Lorem Ipsum Dolar Saint Lorem Ipsum Dolar Saint Lorem Ipsum Dolar Saint Lorem Ipsum Dolar Saint
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Height given to card image box based on the content height